# Phalcon\Mvc\Model and composite primary key

Tags: php, composite-primary-key, phalcon

I use Phalcon\Mvc\Model for all entities in my project (to keep things standartized).
Today i had to import maxmind geoip database in my mysql database to implement native relationships between some entities and maxmind locations (and blocks).

Maxmind database is delivered in csv by default, so how to organize it in mysql - is a question that every developer has to solve according to his needs. Maxmind database contains 2 files:

1. GeoLiteCity-Blocks.csv  (stores ip ranges)
2. GeoLiteCity-Location.csv (stores information about location)

Most tutorials advice to use following table definition for storing table with ip ranges:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GeoLiteCity_Blocks` (
  `startIpNum` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `endIpNum` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `locId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`startIpNum`,`endIpNum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

As you see there is composite primary key. Is it ok to use such key in Phalcon\Mvc\Model? I suppose there are some limits (logically, they should exist, for example, i can't predict Phalcon\Mvc\Model::findFirst($key) method behaviour)

Really, i don't care about disk size, that this table will use, for me only one thing is important - performance. Also i would like to keep all models standartized, not to remember huge amount of small aspects for each entity/table.

So, my question: is it ok to use Phalcon\Mvc\Model with composite key or it is better to make one extra `id` column, that will be primary key & add index to `startIpNum` and `endIpNum` to make selects faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phalcon\Mvc\Model can be used with tables that have composite primary keys. However, the findFirst shortcut is not available, you can do:

```
GeoLiteBlocks::findFirst(array(
   'startipnum = ?0 AND endipnum = ?1',
   'bind' => array($start, $end)
));
```

Also, a method could be added to the model to reduce the coding:

```
class GeoLiteBlocks extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function static findBlock($start, $end)
    {
        return self::findFirst(array(
           'startipnum = ?0 AND endipnum = ?1',
           'bind' => array($start, $end)
        ));
    }
}
```